# Exception Handling....in Xcode/Obj-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception

Is there a feature in Xcode to do something like this:

Select a section of source code, chose a refactoring or similar type menu option and the IDE would then wrap the source code in a try/catch block with all the exceptions that could be thrown based on the Class API's used in the selected code?

As a second question, I'm more familar with OO languages where a significant portion of the code is wrapped in try/catch blocks in a production applciation. For example; if an attempt is made to access an array with an invalid index then an "ArrayOutOfBoundsException" would be thrown at runtime, and would be handled by the try/catch block surrounding the code. Is there a similar mechanism is Objective-C? Although I do see that Objective C supports try/catch blocks and expection handling with NSException, I just donot see it used much in the code of the sample projects, or in general which exceptions a given class may throw in the Class References. However I have not yet been thru to many of the class references.

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question: No. Consider filing an enhancement request with Apple.

For your second question: It has already been covered by other questions on Stack Overflow like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324284/how-to-throw-an-exception-in-objective-c-cocoa), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007106/using-exception-handling-versus-nserror-in-cocoa-apps), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503348/returning-errors-in-objective-c), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546249/what-are-best-practices-for-error-handling-when-writing-an-api-for-the-iphone). The search box is your friend.